# BeginExecuteReader Async Operation with specific instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader, asynchronous

I have three classes, BookingItem, BookingHistoryItem, and BookingManager in an ASP.NET site.

The bookingManager is used for looking up a list of "Change of Booking" transactions in the database. This occurs because I want to look up all of the changes to any Booking (represented by a BookingItem) that occurred "today"

The BookingItem has a property of a list which will represent all previous states of the booking. ex: booking was originally for January 4th, but was moved to January Tenth, and the name was changed from Alistair Smith to Smythe. The booking Item represents what the actually valid booking currently is (as it is also the latest created item in the history table as well), while the history should contain the one for the 4th that was for Alistair Smith, and any other previous versions.

I am iterating through the results of the Search (non-asynchronously) and would like to Asynchronously lookup the booking history items, create the list, and add it to that booking, but I think I am misunderstanding how the BeginExecuteReader with Callback works. I think I need a bit of help with my logic and to understand how AND WHY it could be better.

Example:

```
public class BookingItem
{


    public int BookingID{ get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public DateTime bookingTime{ get; set; }
    public List<BookingHistoryItem> BookingHistory {get; set;}
    public BookingItem()
    {
    }
}
public class BookingHistoryItem
{

    public int TransactionID{ get; set; }        
    public DateTime BookingDate{ get; set; }
    public int BookingID{ get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public DateTime bookingTime{ get; set; }
    public List<BookingHistoryItem> BookingHistory {get; set;}
    public BookingHistoryItem()
    {
    }
}
public class BookingHistoryItem
{

    public int TransactionID{ get; set; }        
    public DateTime BookingDate{ get; set; }
    public int BookingID{ get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public DateTime bookingTime{ get; set; }
    public List<BookingHistoryItem> BookingHistory {get; set;}
    public BookingItem()
    {
    }
}

public class BookingManager
{
     public DateTime StartRange { get; set; }
     public DateTime EndRange { get; set; }

     string strSQL= @"Select * from [Bookings] Where BookingDate Between @Start and @End";
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCFRSQL, conSQL)) 
     {
            //start and end parameters are the selected range from the UI.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = StartRange.ToShortDateString();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = EndRange.ToShortDateString();
            //initializes conSQL
            ConnectToDB();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read()) 
                {
                  /*Here I sort of Asynchronously look it up using BeginReader 
                  and a callback but I don't know how to add the History info to the
                  Booking Item as when it comes back to the actual thread, I have no 
                  reference to this specific booking Item. I want to go through all 
                  Changes, build the booking, add the history, and THEN I will go on to 
                  apply my rules. */
                }
            }
      }
}
```

This is a rough approximation of where I am at. My function for looking up history is as follows, with the callback method:
    public void GetHistory(BookingItem curBook, bool useAsync)
        {

```
        ConnectToDB();
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqcBookingHistory = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * from [BookingHistory] Where BookingID=@BookingID, conSQL);
        sqcBookingHistory .CommandTimeout = 320;
        sqcBookingHistory .CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqcBookingHistory .Parameters.Add("@BookingID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = curBook.BookingID;


        try
        {
            IAsyncResult result = sqcBookingHistory .BeginExecuteReader(MyEndHistoryCallback, sqcBookingHistory);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
            // handle any execution initiation errors here
        }



    }
public void MyEndHistoryCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            // obtain the results from the database instance in the AsyncState
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqcBookingHistory = (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;
            using (IDataReader dr = sqcBookingHistory .EndExecuteReader(result))
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //build BookingHistory Item here
                    //now how I put but it back into the bookingItem that originally 
                    //INitiated it? curBook is a new item.
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
            // handle any execution completion errors here
        }
    }
```

I'm usually pretty smart, but I feel like this is pretty dumb. I admit it, and want to learn how to do this the "best practices" way.

Bottom Line: Retrieve a set of booking transaction items, build booking item (as the change item represents the latest booking) want to iterate through them and build a bookinghistoryitem for each booking, and add it as a property to the original bookingItem. Asynchronously seemed like the fastest way, so multiple bookings are retrieving their history at the same time, instead of bookingitem >whats my history, booking item > what's my hsitory? So from a booking I can say, go get the history and add it to me, so the program can go onto the next one.

Comment: some of the code may be inconsistent such as a variable name slightly different as I sort of re-wrote it so as to not to put company code on here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles